# PHP won't display any errors

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

I have a PHP page that's erroring out somewhere (it loads blank white, no title or anything), but I cannot for the life of me get it to display errors. I have the following in my files, but the page still loads blank white. What can I do to get PHP to display errors? This is on PHP 5.5 on my own server, and I am editing the correct `php.ini` file (according to `phpinfo()`).

php.ini:

```
display_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

.htaccess:

```
php_value error_reporting -1
```

Specific file in question:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Have you checked the error.log? Everything looks fine so far..

Comment: I don't see anything of any significance in the log file at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Server restarted? Which SAPI? phpinfo checked? Tried a wrapper script with `set_error_handler("var_dump")`? What does `php -l` say?

Comment: Intentionally add a syntax error and check if the file is executed.

Comment: @mario: Restarted the server. SAPI is "apache2handler". `phpinfo()` shows that `display_errors` is Off, even though it's pulling from the correct `php.ini` file and that file definitely has `display_errors = on`. Can't get `set_error_handler` to produce anything. Not sure how to invoke `php -l`, calling that from the command line does nothing.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: No effect.

Comment: You need to restart apache after changing the config

Comment: I did restart apache after changing the config, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add it to the correct php.ini file. Some web hosters have configured their server such that a php.ini in the same directory as the html of php file will be executed. But this is not the default. If you are in Linux, try putting it into /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini or search on your harddisk for any php.ini.

Comment: I've made sure that I'm editing the correct `php.ini` file. Just updated the OP to clarify that. Sorry, and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `display_errors` was already set below my own edits, so `php.ini` was using the default value of `Off` instead of my value. Deleted my edits and fixed the spots that needed it, problem resolved.